# Particle accelerators use a beam or single particle?

Tags: particle-accelerators

In textbooks the trajectory of a single particle is always shown, but in real life is a single particle or a beam of particles used?

Comment: Depends a lot on what accelerator you are talking about. Some (Cockroft-Walton or Van de Graaff) can be continuous, linacs and cyclotrons and their descendants are all pulses. Whether a 'pulse' is a single ion or not is a question of the experimental setup.

Answer (score 0):

A beam is used which contains millions of individual particles. Those particles are usually formed into bunches which travel through the accelerator as separated groups; the bunch positions in the "beam" are carefully tracked so they enter the detector array and arrive in the interaction space at exactly the right moment.

Comment: High brightness/luminosity beams certainly have lots of particles in fairly close quarters (if you start worrying about space charge effects you have one of those). On the other hand, standard beam currents (nA) of electrons in a 200keV TEM result in roughly 1 electron in the column at a time. And a single ion implant system has, well, one atom per pulse going through the machine.